# How can I change Color appearance of Segmented Picker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I have four colors of red, green, yellow, and blue and I want my selected segment to have a background/tint color that is indicative of the color name.
This is my code:

```
let objectColors = Color.allCases

@State private var selectedColorIndex = 0

//declared inside body view

Picker("Colors", selection: $selectedColorIndex) {

        ForEach(0..<objectColors.count){ index in

            Text(self.objectColors[index].rawValue).tag(index)

        }

    }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    .padding(10)
    .onAppear {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.generateUIColor(colorIndex: selectedColorIndex)        
    }
```

This is the list I'm pulling from

```
enum Color: String, CaseIterable {
    case red, yellow, green, blue
}
```

I've tried using onChange or onReceive (and Combine's 'Just()' for subview)  instead of onAppear but they crash on playgrounds and don't work on Xcode.
I also saw a WWDC video on UIAction that I think will work great for updating view changes but I have no idea how to translate it. Does anyone one have any suggestions or help, please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here: Since you are using `enum` then selected type should be `enum` type as well, also you had wrong naming for your custom `enum`.

---

### [image]

### Version 1.0.0:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedColor: ColorEnum = ColorEnum.blue
    
    @State private var renderView: Bool = Bool()

    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            
            if renderView { SegmentedPickerView(selectedColor: $selectedColor) }
            else { SegmentedPickerView(selectedColor: $selectedColor) }
            
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedColor) { _ in renderView.toggle() }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct SegmentedPickerView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedColor: ColorEnum

    init(selectedColor: Binding<ColorEnum>) {
        
        self._selectedColor = selectedColor
        
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = selectedColor.wrappedValue.ColorValue
        
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Picker("", selection: $selectedColor) {
                
                ForEach(ColorEnum.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                    
                }
                
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Text("You selected: " + selectedColor.rawValue)
                .bold()
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .padding()

        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.1).cornerRadius(10.0))
        .foregroundColor(Color(selectedColor.ColorValue))
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

---

```
enum ColorEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    
    case red, yellow, green, blue
    
    var ColorValue: UIColor {
        
        get {
            
            switch self {
            case .red: return UIColor.red
            case .yellow: return UIColor.yellow
            case .green: return UIColor.green
            case .blue: return UIColor.blue
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my old Answer with new Version of it, now you can just use **AdvancedSegmentedPicker** in your View, and work with it like a normal **SegmentedPicker** with this deference that you are able to change and update all colors on **SegmentedPicker**, like:

***backgroundColor***

***selectedSegmentTintColor***

***selectedSegmentForegroundColor***

***normalSegmentForegroundColor***

---

you could use like:

```
AdvancedSegmentedPicker(items:selectedItem:)
```

Or:

```
AdvancedSegmentedPicker(items:selectedItem:backgroundColor:selectedSegmentTintColor:selectedSegmentForegroundColor:normalSegmentForegroundColor:)
```

*Also Notice that this **AdvancedSegmentedPicker** is **not** hard coded for just this project, as long as you gave `items` and `selectedItem` to **AdvancedSegmentedPicker**, you can use it in any project, and you could do your color customization as well.*

---

### Version 2.0.0:

### [image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items: [ColorEnum] = ColorEnum.allCases
    @State private var selectedItem: ColorEnum = ColorEnum.blue
    
    @State private var backgroundColor: UIColor?
    @State private var selectedSegmentTintColor: UIColor?
    @State private var selectedSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor?
    @State private var normalSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30.0) {
            
            AdvancedSegmentedPicker(items: items, selectedItem: $selectedItem, backgroundColor: backgroundColor, selectedSegmentTintColor: selectedSegmentTintColor,
                                    selectedSegmentForegroundColor: selectedSegmentForegroundColor, normalSegmentForegroundColor: normalSegmentForegroundColor)
            
            Text("You selected: " + selectedItem.rawValue)
                .bold()
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .padding()
            
            Button("update backgroundColor") {
                
                if backgroundColor == UIColor.gray { backgroundColor = nil }
                else { backgroundColor = UIColor.gray }
                
            }
            
            Button("update selectedSegmentForegroundColor") {
                
                if selectedSegmentForegroundColor == UIColor.white { selectedSegmentForegroundColor = nil }
                else { selectedSegmentForegroundColor = UIColor.white }
                
            }
            
            Button("update normalSegmentForegroundColor") {
                
                if normalSegmentForegroundColor == UIColor.white { normalSegmentForegroundColor = nil }
                else { normalSegmentForegroundColor = UIColor.white }
                
            }
            
        }
        .font(Font.body.bold())
        .onAppear() { selectedSegmentTintColor = selectedItem.ColorValue }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newValue in selectedSegmentTintColor = newValue.ColorValue }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.1).cornerRadius(10.0))
        .padding()
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct AdvancedSegmentedPicker<T: CustomStringConvertible & Hashable>: View {
    
    var items: [T]
    @Binding var selectedItem: T
    
    var backgroundColor: UIColor? = nil
    var selectedSegmentTintColor: UIColor? = nil
    var selectedSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor? = nil
    var normalSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor? = nil
    
    @State private var renderView: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return Group {
            
            if renderView { SegmentedPickerView(items: items, selectedItem: $selectedItem, backgroundColor: backgroundColor, selectedSegmentTintColor: selectedSegmentTintColor,
                                                selectedSegmentForegroundColor: selectedSegmentForegroundColor, normalSegmentForegroundColor: normalSegmentForegroundColor) }
            else { SegmentedPickerView(items: items, selectedItem: $selectedItem, backgroundColor: backgroundColor, selectedSegmentTintColor: selectedSegmentTintColor,
                                       selectedSegmentForegroundColor: selectedSegmentForegroundColor, normalSegmentForegroundColor: normalSegmentForegroundColor) }
            
            
        }
        .onChange(of: backgroundColor) { _ in renderView.toggle() }
        .onChange(of: selectedSegmentTintColor) { _ in renderView.toggle() }
        .onChange(of: selectedSegmentForegroundColor) { _ in renderView.toggle() }
        .onChange(of: normalSegmentForegroundColor) { _ in renderView.toggle() }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
private struct SegmentedPickerView<T: CustomStringConvertible & Hashable>: View {
    
    var items: [T]
    @Binding var selectedItem: T
    
    init(items: [T], selectedItem: Binding<T>, backgroundColor: UIColor? = nil,
         selectedSegmentTintColor: UIColor? = nil, selectedSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor? = nil, normalSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor? = nil) {
        
        self.items = items
        self._selectedItem = selectedItem
        
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = selectedSegmentTintColor
        
        if let unwrappedSelectedSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor = selectedSegmentForegroundColor {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: unwrappedSelectedSegmentForegroundColor], for: .selected)
        }
        else {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.label], for: .selected)
        }
        
        if let unwrappedNormalSegmentForegroundColor: UIColor = normalSegmentForegroundColor {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: unwrappedNormalSegmentForegroundColor], for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.label], for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("", selection: $selectedItem) {
            
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                
                Text(String(describing: item))
                
            }
            
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
enum ColorEnum: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible { case red, yellow, green, blue
    
    var ColorValue: UIColor {
        
        get {
            
            switch self {
            case .red: return UIColor.red
            case .yellow: return UIColor.yellow
            case .green: return UIColor.green
            case .blue: return UIColor.blue
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    var description: String {
        
        get { return self.rawValue }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

Comment: This solution does not work for two ** Picker** in same page

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple version of what you need. This answer uses [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to "Introspect underlying UIKit components from SwiftUI".

In addition, instead of `UISegmentedControl.appearance()` which is app-wide for all `UISegmentedControl`s, this only affects this specific one which can be a lot more useful.

Here is the working code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let objectColors = SegmentColor.allCases
    @State private var selectedColor = SegmentColor.red
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Colors", selection: $selectedColor) {
            ForEach(objectColors) { color in
                Text(color.rawValue).tag(color)
            }
        }
        .introspectSegmentedControl { segmentedControl in
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = selectedColor.color
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .padding(10)
        .onChange(of: selectedColor) { _ in }
    }
}


enum SegmentColor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case red, yellow, green, blue
    
    var id: String { rawValue }
    
    var color: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .red:      return .red
        case .yellow:   return .yellow
        case .green:    return .green
        case .blue:     return .blue
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I do not think this the best way of using a pod instead of true way, I also down vote.